# RoR how to populate number_field with default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have quantity and quantity_received in a table. I want to populate quantity_received with quantity value however if I overwrite this value next time I load the form I want to display the saved value.

```
  <%= fields_for "purchase_item[]", purchase_item do |f| %>
    <td><%= f.number_field :quantity_received, :min => 1, :value => purchase_item.quantity, :size => 8 %></td>
  <% end %>
```

Does RoR have some built-in function for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the easiest way would be to set it when you store the original `quantity` field to avoid having to set it in the form.

What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: well the thing is if I purchase items today I will receive those in a week from now therefore I can't store it upon creation but later on.

Comment: @Gaelle So, what's wrong with how you're doing it now? Isn't it precisely what you want?

Comment: no because if it populates 10, I type in 9 and save. Next time I load the form it shows 10 not 9. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gaelle You'd only want to populate if no value, so use quantity_received || quantity.

Comment: I get an error with `<%= f.number_field :quantity_received, :min => 1, :value => quantity_received || quantity %>`

Comment: @Gaelle ... You obviously need to use `purchase_item.quantity_received` etc., which the error message would imply.

Comment: Thanks. This time if no value saved it populates with 0 but not quantity

Comment: @Gaelle Does the `quantity_received` field default to 0 in the DB? If so, you need to use some logic to set the value. Seems like there's enough info for you to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was set to 0 by default. Solved

Comment: @Gaelle Ah, yep--I probably should have suspected that, sorry for the confusion. Glad you got it working :)